# Chromium Embedded how to execute a javascript callback from c++?

Tags: javascript, c++, callback, chromium-embedded

Recently I have been trying to bind my application to CEF, the process was slow but I made some progress over the last days. However there is one thing I just can't get to work.

What I want to achieve is:
 1. Registering a callback function within Javascript (These functions will be called when an event happens in my application)
 2. Save the callback.
 3. When the event occurs, execute the registered callback.

Now I got step 1 and 2 to work, but step 3 is where the problem is.
I tested it first by registering a callback and then calling it with an executeCallback() function in Javascript and it worked. But whenever I try to execute the callback from within C++ it doesn't work.

I create the setEventCallback in the onContextCread()

```
CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> object = context->GetGlobal();
CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> simplixObj = CefV8Value::CreateObject(NULL);
object->SetValue("simplix", simplixObj, V8_PROPERTY_ATTRIBUTE_NONE);
func = CefV8Value::CreateFunction("setEventCallback", $simplixHandler);
simplixObj->SetValue("setEventCallback", func, V8_PROPERTY_ATTRIBUTE_NONE);
```

With $simplixHandler being an instance of my own handler.
Here is the setEventCallback in my handler:

```
bool SimplixHandler::setEventCallback(CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> object, const CefV8ValueList& arguments, CefRefPtr<CefV8Value>& retval, CefString& exception)
if (arguments.size() == 2 && arguments[0]->IsString() && arguments[1]->IsFunction()) {
    //Get name of callback
    std::string callbackName = arguments[0]->GetStringValue();
    //Get the current context
    CefRefPtr<CefV8Context> context = CefV8Context::GetCurrentContext();
    //Insert into callbacks
    $callbacks[callbackName] = std::make_pair(context, arguments[1]);

    return true;
}
else if(arguments.size() != 2) {
    exception = CefString("Invalid amount of parameters. Expected 2, received " + arguments.size());
    return false;
}
else {
    exception = CefString("Incompatible parameter types, expected (string, function).");
    return false;
}
```

I then try to execute the callbacks by calling executeCallback:

```
bool SimplixHandler::executeCallback(std::string name, CefRefPtr<CefListValue> list) {
bool handled = false;

if (!$callbacks.empty() && $callbacks.count(name) != 0) {
    std::pair<CefRefPtr<CefV8Context>, CefRefPtr<CefV8Value>> pair = $callbacks[name];
    CefRefPtr<CefV8Context> context = pair.first;
    CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> func = pair.second;

    context->Enter();
    CefV8ValueList callArgs;

    //First argument is function name
    CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> args = CefV8Value::CreateArray(list->GetSize());
    setList(list, args);
    callArgs.push_back(args);

    CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> retval = func->ExecuteFunction(NULL, callArgs);
    if (retval.get()) {
        if (retval->IsBool())
            handled = retval->GetBoolValue();
    }

    context->Exit();
}

return handled;
}
```

I call this function from within my SimplixHandler, however I call callbacks by calling the specific event function, example:

```
bool SimplixHandler::notifyDirectoryChanged(std::string directory) {
CefRefPtr<CefListValue> list = CefListValue::Create();

list->SetSize(1);
list->SetString(0, directory);

return executeCallback("onDirectoryChange", list);
}
```

And finally my Javascript:

```
function dirChange(dir) {
    document.getElementById("filename").innerHTML = "It's something";
}

simplix.setEventCallback("onDirectoryChange", dirChange);
```

I know the event gets called (because I first had nullpointer exception due to wrong linking of classes, that's fixed now), but the Javascript Callback does not get called.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your line `CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> retval = func->ExecuteFunction(NULL, callArgs);` in `SimplixHandler::executeCallback()` actually being called, or is it not finding the callback?

Answer (score 0):

you can use any function in html code for callback.

Renderer:

```
bool SimpleApp::OnProcessMessageReceived(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
    CefProcessId source_process,
    CefRefPtr<CefProcessMessage> message) 
{
    std::string message_name = message->GetName();

    if( message_name == "FUNC")
    { 
        //AfxMessageBox("stop");

        //browser->GetMainFrame()->ExecuteJavaScript("super_test('works!');", browser->GetMainFrame()->->GetURL(), 0);

        CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> object = m_context->GetGlobal();


        CefRefPtr<CefV8Context> v8context = browser->GetMainFrame()->GetV8Context();
        v8context->Enter(); 

        CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> func_test = object->GetValue("super_test");

        if(func_test == NULL)
        {
            v8context->Exit();
            return false;
        }

        CefV8ValueList arguments;
        CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> test = CefV8Value::CreateString("hello from c++");
        arguments.push_back(test);

        CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> retval = func_test->ExecuteFunction(NULL, arguments);

        v8context->Exit();

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

jScript:

```
 <script>

      function super_test(resp)
      {
          alert(resp);
          return "7777";
      }
```

browser:

```
CefRefPtr<CefProcessMessage> message = CefProcessMessage::Create("FUNC");

        SimpleHandler::GetInstance()->GetBrowser()->SendProcessMessage(PID_RENDERER, message);
```